# Exit browser in full screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chrome, browser, fullscreen

I'm trying to find a way to exit kiosk mode or to exit a full screen chromium.

So I'm running a Raspberry Pi 4 with raspbian and have Netflix, Disney+ etc. working as a link on my desktop. I add the desktop command to be in kiosk mode but there is no way to exit if you only have a touch screen.

A keyboard gives the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to exit but if it is a touch screen there appears no easy way to come out of the full screen browser. So for now I've excluded the kiosk mode and hidden all but the top bar that includes the close button (cross in top right).

That's OK, but it would be nice to somehow do this full screen. Then either by long press and an option to either close tab, exit or show desktop that gets you out of the netflix ... running.

My whole setup looks neat, with 5 streaming services on the desktop, they all run full screen lovely, but no way to exit them. I did look at a mouse gesturing add on for chrome (`crxmouse`), but that really did not work for chrome, let alone chromium. I've come here for some inspiration or maybe another way round it, like a long press to exit or something.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that other people are searching for this but it should not be possible. An interesting solution is in the following post that says

"you will need to install a button that will run a script..."

https://forums.opto22.com/t/shutting-down-kiosk-mode-without-keyboard/1478/5

https://community.element14.com/products/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/w/documents/856/adding-a-shutdown-button-to-the-raspberry-pi-b

the script could use something like `xdotool` to emulate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard button presses (or just `killall chromium`)

https://obrienlabs.net/setup-raspberry-pi-kiosk-chromium/

https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool

I hope you find some inspiration by these :)

Comment: Quite useful answer there, thank you.  I will upvote you when I have enough cudos to do that.   I have so far found a way to get the right click swipe down to work in kiosk mode, however, latest debian has killed right click on touch screens, so I'm working on a way around that in particular.  But this method of making a home button is a good idea and I will add it to my list of things to research